# Laravel eloquent make visible only given attribute in one instance of model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, visible

i have instance model from

```
$model = Model::find(1);
```

for example this instance always return these attribute (some is from $append):

```
-id
-name
-countRelation
-description
-created_at
-updated_at
```

what i want is to only retrive `name` and `description` from this instance;

makeVisible only work to show hidden attribute; i don't want use makeHidden because the result of find may change if on model i add new append attribute;

Comment: is `select` what you need? , like this `Model::select('name', 'description')->find(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are appending accessors limiting the SELECT statement won't stop those from being appended to the serializied output. You can use `setVisible` to do this though:

```
$model->setVisible(['name', 'description']);
```

Setting what is visible this way will limit the attributes, appends and relationships that are returned in the serialized output of the Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` to only retrieve some column in your database, it will not affect `append`, see the doc for more info [`Eloquent`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)

```
$model = Model::find(1);
// to this
$model = Model::select('name', 'description')->find(1);
```

See [`Query Builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) for more insight about grabbing data from database.

Answer (score 0):

if you retrieve **name** and **description** only, then you may use

```
$model = Model::select(['name', 'description'])->find(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select()` to select only certain columns in your query.

```
$model = Model::select('name', 'description')->find(1);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause

You can also get the Model and use functions on the model. If you have a single Model you can use `get()`.

```
$model = Model::find(1)->get('name', 'description');
```

If you have a collection you can use `->map->only()`. This maps the only function as a callback for each Model in your Collection.

```
$models = $models->map->only(['name', 'description']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found **makeVisible(array $column)** working better for me.

```
$model->makeVisible(['wallet']);
```